# How to load polymer element manually

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, polymer

I'm trying to hook up Mocha/Chai/Karma for our testing framework. I have almost got there, using the Polymer unit test guide as a base. I wanted something much simpler, requiring just a `tests.js` script and to use a bower component `vca-tests`. This is how the `tests.js looks:

```
(function() {
  'user strict';
  elementSuite('vca-colour-picker', function() {
    test('setting the web value should be reflected in the RGB values', function(done) {
      this.set(function(element) {
        element.web = '#FFCC88';
      }).then(function(element) {
        assert.equal(element.r, 255);
        assert.equal(element.g, 204);
        assert.equal(element.b, 136);
      });
    });
  });
}());
```

So I wrote a Mocha test runner:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>VCA Element Test Runner</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- Load in the frameworks we need -->
    <script src="../platform/platform.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="vca-tests.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `elementSuite` function loads in the component from the route of the repository into an `<iframe>`. Due to the way `bower` works I need to modify the location of the imports. The `vca-test.html` in loaded from inside the `bower_components` folder:

```
<!-- Test frameworks -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../mocha/mocha.css" />
<script src="../mocha/mocha.js"></script>
<script src="../chai/chai.js"></script>

<!-- Perform some set up -->
<script>
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var iframe,
      documents = {};

  function elementImport(suite, name, done) {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      var i,
          doc = iframe.contentDocument,
          link = doc.createElement('link'),
          win = iframe.contentWindow,
          head = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
          body = doc.body,
          origin = window.location.origin,
          links = this.response.querySelectorAll('link[rel="import"]'),
          element = this.response.querySelector('polymer-element');

      // Fix up the import paths as they will be referencing the root path and we
      // need the relative to the bower components (which is where we are now)
      for (i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
        links[i].href = links[i].href.replace(origin, '..');
        doc.adoptNode(links[i]);
        head.appendChild(links[i]);
      }

      // Make sure polymer is fired up
      doc.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// At this point we have loaded all of the dependent components of the
// component to test but we still need to be able to create instances
// of the component. The below code will work, but because it is loaded
// to the root of the repository all the dependencies will fail with 404s

        /*/ Import the rest of the component
        link.rel = 'import';
        link.href = '../../' + name + '.html';
        link.import = this.response;
        head.appendChild(link);/**/

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Create the element
        suite.ctx.element = doc.createElement(name);
        body.appendChild(suite.ctx.element);

        // Tell mocha that we are done
        done();
      }, false);
    }
  }

  function elementLoad(name, done) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        path = '../../' + name + '.html';
    xhr.open('GET', path, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'document';
    xhr.onload = elementImport.bind(xhr, this, name, done);
    xhr.send();
  }

  function elementSetup(name, done) {
    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.cssText = /*'position: absolute;left:-10000em;*/'width:768px;height:1024px';
    iframe.onload = elementLoad.bind(this, name, done);
    iframe.src = 'iframe.html';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    // Provide convience functions
    this.ctx.set = function(callback) {
      callback.call(this, this.element);
      Platform.flush();
      return this;
    };
    this.ctx.then = function(callback) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        callback.call(this, this.element);
        this.test.callback();
      }.bind(this), 50);
      return this;
    };
  }

  function elementTeardown() {
//    document.body.removeChild(iframe);
  }

  // This is what the tests.js script uses to register an element to test
  window.elementSuite = function(name, tests) {
    suite(name, function() {
      setup(elementSetup.bind(this, name));
      teardown(elementTeardown);
      tests();
    });
  }

  // We use chai as our assertion framework
  window.assert = chai.assert;

  // Mocha runs our tests
  mocha.setup({ui: 'tdd', slow: 1000, timeout: 5000});
}());
</script>

<!-- Load in the test script -->
<script src="../../tests.js"></script>

<!-- Run the tests -->
<script>
mocha.run();
</script>
```

So my question boils down to this: **How can I XHR a HTML document containing a `polymer-element` but change the base `href` so that my relative bower components load?**

Polymer seems to do some magic when the `<link rel="import">` is loaded to make the element available.

Comment: Looking at the internals of the Polymer code, using a `data:` URI as the `href` is supported but the Polymer HTMLImports polyfill doesn't seem to support it. Looking at a patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: HTML imports do not support `data:text/html` in the specification, so this will *only* work when using the polyfill.

Did it using a horrible monkey patch:

```
// Do a local import
link.rel = 'import';
link.href = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(component);

// Monkey Patch Polymer, to fake the location of the 'import'
if (iframe.contentWindow.HTMLImports && !iframe.contentWindow.HTMLImports.useNative) {
  var hi = iframe.contentWindow.HTMLImports,
      importLoader = hi.importLoader,
      receive = importLoader.receive,
      origin = iframe.src.substr(0, iframe.src.lastIndexOf('/', iframe.src.lastIndexOf('/') - 1));
  importLoader.receive = function(args) {
    if (arguments[0] === link.href) {
      var i, redirected = [];
      for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        redirected.push(arguments[i]);
      }
      redirected.push(origin + '/' + name + '/' + name + '.html');
      receive.apply(this, redirected);
    } else {
      receive.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
}

// Add the link now that we are monkey patched
doc.head.appendChild(link);
```

The `HTMLImports` doesn't handle data URIs correctly at the time of writing. Not sure how to write a patch for the project at the moment.

Comment: I implemented this into a Karma plugin for easy re-use: https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-polymer-test